# Is a char saved in memory as an entire word with padding?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, char

I'm working with char arrays in C and I came across a strange phenomenon.
The essential code:

```
char buffer[2];
buffer[0] = 0x7F; /*until this value I get normal behaviour*/
buffer[1] = 0x80; /*from this value I get leading ones*/
printf("%X\n", buffer[0]);
printf("%X\n", buffer[1]);
```

This prints:

```
7F
FFFFFF80
```

Just to make sure I checked

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(char));
printf("%d\n", sizeof(int*));
```

And as expected I received:

```
1
4
```

So a char is 1 byte and a word is 4 bytes on my machine (32-bit, x86, little endian, Ubuntu 12.04.5 VM).

And when I send an entire word to `printf()` I get 1 padding.
I could live with zero padding, but this is strange...

1. Does anyone have an explanation?
2. Is a char array not really a sequence of chars, but a sequence of words where we regard only the first byte?  (The implication is that a char array and an int array of the same length will take the same amount of space in memory)

Comment: Try declaring `unsigned char buffer[2]`.

Comment: To print a `char`'s value in hex use `hhx` or `hhX`.

Comment: Your characters are indeed 1 byte; what you're seeing is called *sign extension*.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks 'unsigned char' fixed the printing. But what about question 2? Do I have to worry if I'm doing fancy bitwise manipulations in my buffer like shifting?

Comment: If you don't tell printf its second argument is 1 byte, printf will assume it is 4 bytes in this case. The same code would not work on big endian environments.

Comment: @NimrodMorag As to question 2, a char array really is a sequence of chars, not words.

Comment: You probably wanted to check `printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));` without the asterisk...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Language

> Is a char saved in memory as an entire word with padding?"

**No.** An object always occupies `sizeof(type)` bytes.

That is one of the fundamentals in C. It could not be otherwise, because arrays are accessed through pointers. In order to advance a pointer to the next array element the compiler adds `sizeof(type)` to its numerical value.

This implies, by the way, that the alignment requirements for a type can not be larger than its size (because array elements cannot have padding between them). In particular, a char can be placed at an address of arbitrary alignment.

Note that it is not required that all bits or bytes in a type are actually "used", i.e. part of the determination of the value an object has. But any unused bytes will dutifully be reported as part of the object by `sizeof()`.

Note also that the compiler may (and often does) choose to *place* objects strategically at well-aligned addresses.

A common example for both caveats are struct members which often have padding *between* each other. The overall size of the struct then includes the padding bytes, even if they happen to be at the end.

### The Details

As so often, the details are a bit involved. I'll do a step-by-step walk-through, citing [the last C ISO standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) as I go.

**1. Calling a function with an ellipsis `...` in the prototype**

When the function parameter types are not known because the function doesn't have a prototype or the prototype has an ellipsis like with `printf`, C prescribes a simplification of the argument types -- they are all converted to one of a smaller subset of types. These are the so-called **"default argument promotions"**.

The first step in the default promotions is to perform the **integer promotions.**<sup>1</sup> All integer arguments (`char`, `short` etc.) are converted to `int` if all values of the original type can be represented in an `int` (6.3.1.1/2). This is the case with your `char` argument.<sup>2</sup>

**2. Integer conversion**

Your argument is a char with the value 0x80. This is in binary `1000 0000`, i.e. the highest bit is set and the other bits are zero. `char` on your system must be signed; the highest bit is therefore the sign bit, meaning 0x80 is a negative number. The value of this integer (not `int`!) argument is the smallest signed number representable in 8 bits in 2's-complement representation. It has the value of a positive number with all zero bits in the original number set to 1, plus one, and then changing the sign: 0x7f (127) plus 1, which is 128, negated: -128. -128 represented in 32 bit 2's-complement simply is 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000, or 0xff ff ff 80. No secret change of value, all to the contrary.

If, on the other hand, you declare the argument `unsigned char`, the bit pattern 1000 0000 represents the value 128, whose 32 bit representation is, unsurprisingly, 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000, or 0x00 00 00 80.

One of these two bit patterns on the stack is what `printf()` receives as arguments<sup>3</sup>, depending on your argument type (signed or unsigned char).

**3. Inside printf**

As discussed, `printf()` always *receives* an `int` argument, no matter whether the *supplied* `char` argument was signed or unsigned. (The `int`
will have a different value though.)

`printf()` will then use the format string to determine (1) that the argument must be an `int`; and (2) how to convert it back to its original type before producing a textual representation from it. The length modifier `hh` "specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a signed char or unsigned char argument **(the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing)".**<sup>6</sup>

Finally the `X` specifies to "convert the `unsigned int` argument to unsigned hexadecimal notation".<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>6.5.2.2/6. The second step is converting `float`s to `double`s.

<sup>2</sup>One interesting consequence of these rules is that `printf()` -- like any other function with variable argument lists -- can never see a parameter of type `char` (it will always have been converted to an `int`).

<sup>3</sup>On a 2's-complement architecture.

<sup>4</sup>7.21.6.1/7.

<sup>5</sup>7.21.6.1/8. I'm a bit unsure about this wording because my parsing of the draft leads me to believe that no `unsigned int` is ever involved (we may have an `unsigned char` which is always promoted to a (signed) `int`). No `unsigned int` in sight. (Did this change some time since 1989?) This would mean that `printf("%hhX", (unsigned char)0x80)` is UB because the conversion X is applied to something which is not an `unsigned int` (namely an `int`). The technically correct form would be `printf("%hhX", (unsigned int)(unsigned char)0x80)` -- an `unsigned int` argument will be left alone by the integer promotions. (I'm fairly sure nobody would write that, and the first form will produce the proper result on all machines.)

<sup>6</sup>7.29.2.1/7

Answer (score 3):

`printf` doesn't know how large each argument is; you have to tell it, in this case using the `hh` length specifier:

```
printf("%hhX\n", buffer[1]);
```

However, the behavior in your case is still well-specified, since arguments smaller than `int` are promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` in a manner that has to be equivalent to either 0-padding or sign extension.

Comment: The `%hhX` modifier fixed the printing, thank you. Can you answer my second question about array storage?

Comment: @NimrodMorag See my answer. The interaction between arrays, pointers and `sizeof()` is the reason why objects always need exactly `sizeof()` space.

Comment: Pedantic detail:  Printing a negative `char` is not well defined with `"%X"`.  `"%X"` expects an `unsigned` and with a negative `char`, C11 exemption §6.5.2.2 does not apply.  The `"hh"` does not prevent the _technical_ problem.  Yet this UB typically "works" as desired on _so many_ platforms that it is _practically_ defined..  OTOH, OP's `buffer[1] = 0x80;` is not well defined either with a signed_ `char`.

Answer (score 1):

The `char` datatype is a signed integer quantity. When integer types are put into a parameter list for a function call in C, they are passed as `int`. Since `char` is rated as signed by your compiler, and the value `0x80` has its high bit on, it is sign-extended when it is implicitly cast to an `int` for `printf`.

To prevent that extension, tell the compiler that you want an `unsigned` value:

```
printf("%X\n", (unsigned char) buffer[1]);
```

The `char` will still be promoted to `int` for the parameter list, but in this case it will become `0x00000080`.

Comment: Actually, strictly speaking, it's implementation-defined whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: .. yes, if you want a `char` that is always with sign, use `signed char`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, strictly speaking, that is correct. But it's clear that in this implementation, `char` is signed. I'll amend my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Logicrat Right.  Just say "The `char` datatype is usually a signed integer quantity."